# POSTGRESQL ERROR:more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
SELECT

  (SELECT vch_message
     FROM TABLE1
       WHERE  vch_message like 'DONE%'
    ) as Status,
 (SELECT vch_Type
     FROM TABLE2
       WHERE  vch_Type like 'Account'
    ) as Type

From Table3
where Condition
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Why not :

```
SELECT
   Status.vch_message,
   Type.vch_Type 
From
   Table3,
   (
      SELECT
         vch_message 
      FROM
         TABLE1 
      WHERE
         vch_message like 'DONE%' 
   )
   as Status,
   (
      SELECT
         vch_Type 
      FROM
         TABLE2 
      WHERE
         vch_Type like 'Account' 
   )
   as Type 
WHERE
   Condition
```

Comment: Unrelated: today I (hope to) get to legendary gold ... just saying thanks to all the folks I learned so much from ...

Comment: congra @LegendaryGoldCat should i call you GhostCat or Legendary GoldCat by now i'm happy for you bro i will be happy for you to get 100.000 rep ;)

Comment: Either way is fine. And I will change back the nick name later on of course (although I think it is now locked in for 30 days). And yes: *if* I would continue like lately, I hit 100K sometime in summer 2018. But I am not sure if I will continue pulling in 200+ points per day, now that the legendary badge counter stopped ticking.

Comment: just continue @LegendaryGoldCat like you was you are good and i'm happy for you and alwayse happy to see your name in top https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers :)